# Custom formatter calling in jqgrid not worked

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am trying to call a formatter function from my jqgrid. I put an alert inside my formatter function, but it is not worked. I followed http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter tutorial.

Here is my code:

```
function jqGridMethod() {
    var jsonData = {
        "model" : [ {
            "name" : "code",
            "index" : "code",
            "width" : "100",
            "sortable" : false,
            "editable" : false,
            formatter : "showlink",
            formatoptions : {
                baseLinkUrl : 'javascript:',
                showAction : "seasonEdit('",
                addParam : "');"
            }
        }, {
            "name" : "name",
            "index" : "name",
            "width" : 100
        },{
            "name" : "colorCode",
            "index" :"colorCode" ,
            "width" : 100,
            formatter:colorformatter

        },{
            "name" : "startDay",
            "index" : "startDay",
            "width" : 100
        }, {
            "name" : "startMonth",
            "index" : "startMonth",
            "width" : 100
        },{
            "name" : "endDay",
            "index" : "endDay",
            "width" : 100
        },{
            "name" : "endMonth",
            "index" : "endMonth",
            "width" : 100
        },{
            "name" : "encryption",
            "index" : "encryption",
            "width" : "100",
            "hidden" : true,
        } ],
        "sort" : {
            "sortcount" : "2",
            "sortColumn1" : "#jqgh_jqGrid_list_grid_code",
            "sortColumn2" : "#jqgh_jqGrid_list_grid_name"
        },
        "column" : [ "Code", "Name","Color","Start Day","Start Month","End Day","End Month", "Encryption" ],
        "url" : {
            "serverurl" : "/pms/season/list"
        },
    };
    jqGridData(jsonData);
}
/////////////////////////////////


   function colorformatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    //return '<img src="'+cellvalue+'" />';

    alert("cellvalue"+cellvalue);
// format the cellvalue to new format
    var myGrid = $('#jqGrid_list_grid'),
    selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
    celValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'Color');
return cellvalue;
}
```

Is there any thing wrong with my code? Why don't my alert gets worked?

I checked inside my browser console. No errors shown there, it indicated that my function is called, but that alert and following code not gets worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted only small part of your code, but one can see many problems inside.

The first one: you should be careful in the type of properties used. For example the value of `width` property of `colModel` items should be the number instead of string (`"width" : 100` instead of `"width" : "100"`). More important that the value of `formatter` property should be the *function* instead of the string which contains the name of the function. JavaScript parses the JavaScript code and sees all variables defined in the same scope (for example you can define `colorformatter` function directly inside of the function `jqGridMethod`) or in the outer scope. If you get the `colModel` *from the server* by using Ajax call then you can't specify the function directly because JSON don't support fuction type. In the case you should use jqGrid version 4.7 or higher (I recommend to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9.2). It allows you to define common templates which uses custom formatter and to use string as the value of `formatter` property. See [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631) for details. Alternatively you can defined custom formatters by setting `colorformatter` property of `$.fn.fmatter` object. See [the code](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) or [another one](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.checkboxFontAwesome4.js) which defines `formatter: "dynamicLink"` and `formatter: "checkboxFontAwesome4"`.

The second important problem is understanding the goal of the formatter. The problem is the following. jqGrid needs to fill the content (the body) of the grid. Web browser provides interface to manipulate the content of HTML page dynamically, but it's very important to understand, that modification of one element on the page follow modification of *other* elements. If you insert a row in the table for example then the position of the rows below and the position of other elements below of the table can be changed. In the same way the CSS style of *other elements* can be changed too. So the web browser have to *recalculate* many properties of all existing elements of the page after any modification of HTML page. The process have the name reflow (see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)). To improve performance of filling of the large grid jqGrid use the following scenario. It collect the content of all body of the grid **as HTML string fragments** and then place `innerHTML` property of `<tbody>` element of the grid as **one operation**. It improves the performance of the filling of the large grid dramatically. Now it should be clear that formatter have to return **HTML fragment of the cell as string**. In the same way you can't use `myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'Color')` to get the value from the grid body because the custom formatter will be called *before* the body will be filled.

If the custom formatter need to access to the value from another column of the same row then it should use `options` or `rowObject` parameters. In case of usage [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you can remove `rowObject` parameter because all information which you need is in `options` already. The rowid of the current filling row are in `options.rowId`. The values from input data for the current row can be found in `options.rowData`. To get the value from `Color` column you can use `options.rowData.Color`.

If you have to use old versions of jqGrid then you should use `rowObject` parameter. The format of the data of `rowObject` object depends on many factors. During the initial filling of the grid the `rowObject` object contains the data *in the same format like input data returned from the server*. If you loads the data from the server in the format

```json
{ 
    "total": "xxx", 
    "page": "yyy", 
    "records": "zzz",
    "rows": [
        {"id":"12", "cell":["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
        {"id":"34", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
          ...
    ]
}
```

then you should use `rowObject[i]` to access `Color` column and you have to use `i` which corresponds the number of the `Color` column in `colModel` array. `options.pos` could be the index which you should use instead of `i`, but the value can distinguish on 1 till 3 depends whether you use or not the options `multiselect: true`, `subGrid: true` or `rownumbers: true`.

If you use another format of input data

```json
{ 
    "total": "xxx", 
    "page": "yyy", 
    "records": "zzz",
    "rows": [
        {"id":"12", "colName1":"cell11", "Color":"cell12", ...},
        {"id":"34", "colName1":"cell21", "Color":"cell22", ...},
          ...
    ]
}
```

then `rowObject.Color` will get you required data.

In case of usage the first (array) format of input data **and** using `loadonce: true` additionally you will have more complex situation. During initial loading of data you will have to use `rowObject[2]` to access `Color`, but during later filling of the grid the format of `rowObject` will be changed and you will have to use `rowObject.Color` instead. So you will have to test whether `rowObject` is array or not and to use the corresponding format. The usage of `rowObject.Color || rowObject[2]` can have you good results.

I described the format of `rowObject` detailed so that you understand the benefit of using free jqGrid 4.9.2 which simplify the code. You can just use `options.rowData.Color` to access the `Color` independent from the format of input data and independent from the usage of `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: ok.i am using java spring mvc for backend.Is this function call correct?

{
   "name" : "colorCode",
   "index" :"colorCode" ,
   "width" : 100,
   formatter:colorformatter
   
  }

Comment: @VishnuM: It's much better, but I would recommend you **never** set `index` property at all. Moreover it's important **where** in your code you defines `colorformatter` function. I don't use java spring myself. Moreover you posts **short fragments** of JavaScript code, but the problem could be exist if you placed the code fragment on the wrong place. Do you make the changes in your code? Is `alert` be called from `colorformatter` now? How look the code of `colorformatter` now? Which version of jqGrid you use? Where is more full current JavaScript code which you use? Do you have any error now?

Comment: I updated my code and posted full portion.But its still not working.

Comment: @VishnuM: Sorry, but **what is not working**? I asked you many question, but you answered almost no one. I still not know which version of jqGrid you use at all. The `colorformatter` function still use old code. It uses `getCell``and don't return anything (it have to return string). You included the code of `jqGridMethod` which returns some information in format close to format of options used by jqGrid, but you use `sort`, `url` and so on which looks strange. I don't see any code which **creates** jqGrid. So it's unclear what you do.

Comment: I am using jqrid 5.0 version.Alert inside colorformatter function is not working.

Comment: @VishnuM: OK you use [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.0, but **I don't see any code which shows how you create jqGrid.** How you creates the grid? You don't see Alert inside `colorformatter`, but what you see at all? Do you see the empty grid? Do you see the grid where the data are filled, but the column `colorCode` is empty? Sorry, but if somebody try to help you for free then you should at lest clear explain your current problem. Moreover I wrote you long answer where I explains the using of `getCell` inside of custom formatter **can't work**, but you still us it.

Comment: I see grid with all columns and all datas.and its working fine.I need to know how to call a function from a formatter field in jq grid.

{
            "name" : "colorCode",
            "index" :"colorCode" ,
            "width" : 100,
            formatter:colorformatter

        }
as specified here....

Comment: @VishnuM: I don't understand what you mean with "how to call a function from a formatter field in jq grid". If everything is working and you have all data then which problem you have? Which function you want call from the formatter? I wrote you that the formatter `colorformatter` should **don't call** `myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'Color')` and to use something like `rowObject.Color` instead. In general you can call **any** function from `colorformatter`, but you can get only the information which **exist at the moment**.

Comment: @VishnuM: OK. I see that the problem is already solved. You are welcome!

Comment: I am new to this Jqgrid,juz started today.It is actually the lack of concepts.Your documentation is really helpfull,It helps me a lot,thankuu

Comment: @VishnuM: You are welcome! I recommend you additionally to try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). [The wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) contains many new features which I implemented. Free jqGrid is alternative to Guriddo jqGrid JS which you use currently. It's the fork which I develop. You can try it by changing URLs (see [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).